# Is there such a thing as an IP to bluetooth gateway?

Tags: ip, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth device I need to communicate with and I have an embedded, fully programmable controller with TCP/IP support but no bluetooth capability.

Is there any way to get my embedded device to communicate with my bluetooth device, like a gateway that can take IP packets and translate them to bluetooth?

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't really provide enough information to answer this definitively for your exact scenario (e.g. you do not specify what your Bluetooth device is, you've provided no details on the controller, etc).

However, it is possible to convert data from a Bluetooth device to TCP/IP. For example, the [Parani-1000 series](http://www.senanetworks.com/products/industrial_bluetooth/index.php?tab_menu=MSP&which_group=bluetooth_ap) is a Bluetooth Access Point that provides a Bluetooth wireless to IP Gateway. These can be used to:

- Create a TCP/IP server or client for your host PC
- Act as a repeater to increase the distance of your network
- Add a Bluetooth hub that allows up to 28 devices to communicate with each other

I have not used this product myself, so can't vouch as to how well it works. And, as I mentioned, your question lacks the detail needed to provide you some certainty. However, you could check out [this page](https://www.kanda.com/serial-wireless.html) on Kanda's website that has a diagram showing how the Parani-1000 series works.